# How do I port a chrome extension to firefox add-on with promises and callbacks

Tags: firefox-addon, porting, firefox-addon-webextensions, webextension-polyfill

I am porting a chrome extention to firefox. The extentions UI displays it's sign-up and sign-in form but after a succesfull sign-in the extentions (popup) goes blank, Can anyone point me to the right direction?  I am looking at my manifest.json and backgroung script  but everything seems to be in order.
Thank you

I have installed running webpack plugings for development webpack-webext-plugin and webextension-polyfill... but still noting changes

Answer (score 0):

Most chrome extension should work in Firefox with minor changes. The [manifest.json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json) is also very similar.

Without seeing the code, it is difficult to see if there are any issues.

AFA callback vs promise, there is no need to change. The callback chrome.*** API is also supported by Firefox.